# Could put input when changing focus from WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have UserControl WPF and I run in a Popup window mode.
If I run the program, and change the focus like mouse trigger on the
extended monitor and go back to the WPF Popup window I could not
put inputs in textbox anymore.

I am expecting that when getting back my focus to the WPF textbox, i could still input.